# How to find the number of $n$ for which $n!$ is divisble by $a$ but not $b$?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

The values of $a$ and $b$ are known . I need to find the number of $n$ for which $n!$ is divisible by $a$ and not by $b$.

Suppose $a=2$ , $ b=3$ then the possible solution is $1$ only for $n=2$.

Comment: If b divides a it is not possible. Give conditions or restrictions for a and b, I think it would be better.

Comment: $1 \le a \le b \le 10^7$ Only this is known.

Comment: @axyz: Your last paragraph makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry for that, it was a typo.

Comment: @barakmanos: I misread the question too, at first. axyz is asking for the _number_ of integers $n$ such that $a$ divides $n!$ and $b$ doesn't. This is well defined for all $a,b$.

Comment: Do you want a formula ? Also, does $0!$ count in the case $a=1$ ?

Comment: Note that $b|n!$ for all $n\ge b$. So, you only need to consider the numbers $n<b$.

Comment: @Peter,If such a formula exists otherwise i am looking for an algorithm . $0!$ can be a solution.

Comment: If the largest prime factor of $a$ is $p$, then you can start with $p!$ because it is the smallest factorial that can be divisible by $a$. And you can stop when $n!$ is divisible by $b$ because every greater factorial is also divisible by $b$. So, the problem can be reduced to the problem : Find the smallest factorial which is divisible by a given number.

Answer (score 1):

If $n(m)$ denotes the smallest number $n$ such that $m|n!$, then the number of solutions is $\max${$0,n(b)-n(a)$}.